# sed using mac and Dollar sign

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I am running a script and this is part of it:

```
cat ../my_file.txt | sed -e $'s/\t#.*$/found_pattern/g'
```

This is quite working. So far, so good. Now I want to use this part as a variable `$'s/\t#.*$/found_pattern/g'`

When I am trying to run the following it wont work:

```
THISVAR="$'s/\t#.*$/found_pattern/g'"
cat ../my_file.txt | sed -e ${THISVAR}
```

I think the dollar sign won't get interpreted.
Can you guys help me out?

Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: What's the plan to use a sed expression as a variable ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot I wanted to create a bash script for linux and mac. In mac I have to use the $ sign to get the 'tab' (\t) interpreted, in linux I don't. So I wanted to build something universal :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put $ in quotes it became part of the variable's value instead of being used as a meta-character to interpret escape sequences. Try this:

```
THISVAR=$'s/\t#.*$/found_pattern/g'
cat ../my_file.txt | sed -e "$THISVAR"
```

Double-quote `THISVAR` to interpret the variable but prevent shell from tokenizing its value before passing to sed.

Also, you don't need the `cat` - just pass the file name to sed directly.

```
sed -e "$THISVAR" ../my_file.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps also mention that the double quotes around `"$THISVAR"` are also quite significant.

Comment: And maybe lose the [useless use of `cat`](/q/11710552) too.

Comment: @tripleee I initially wanted to focus on the OP's main issue re: variables so didn't touch the cat part. Added it now. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out.